# Error in Google Webmaster tools

Tags: seo, google-search-console

Google Webmaster tools says I have many faults. I wonder how I might supposed to improve them in a way such as to make a `robot.txt` to the server? Where I decide where you should go, etc? ..

You can see the picture here what I mean:

[image]

However, it must be said that I have made that about 2 times before so there have been many mistakes.

But I have used woorank to help me a lot further to see what I was missing on the page.

So, my question is simply: does `robot.txt` have anything to do with it, all the old mistakes? ..

This is what my page NOT out more!

[image]

Could it not also help a little of everything if I had a sitemap for my site?

*Just tell if you do not understand what I mean. However, I am **dyslexic** so is bad for English ..*

Comment: What are the "faults"? Is there anything listed below the graph you posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the screen shot I understand "Ikke fundet" means "Not Found".

Google bot is unable to find some pages in your site that existed in past but now it is not there on your website.

If you have removed any pages from the site or changed the URL of any page, then simply **update your sitemap** and resubmit it to the Google webmaster. This is a serious issue so do it ASAP.

Robots.txt has nothing to do with this.